How to prevent Objects that are displayd side by side to influence each other?
I have created a report that displays objects side by side. Here is how I set up the objects in Report Builder:

When rendering this report one Tablix gets pushed down by the subreports. The upper two Textfields are not affected by this issue.

This issue even prevails when the subreport is hidden by an expression:

In short: I would like to prevent the secont Tablix (Headlined "Portfolio Characteristics") to get pushed down by the reports on the right hand side.
Upon researching on the platform tried the follwoing solutions:

I put both sides (the right and the left one) into separate rectangles
I put the Subreports into a separate Tablix so I could provide an expression to hide the row
I put the second Tablix ("Portfolio Characteristics") also into a Subreport in order to mimick the behavior of the "Top positions" Tablix

None of the attempts above worked. The Tablix "Portfolio Characteristics" still gets pushed down.

It doesn't look like there should be extra space between the two charts. Are you sure the Allocation sub doesn't have extra space at the bottom?
